# No primitive over an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi I’m struggling over this exercice.

Show that $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, f(z)= \frac {1}{z^2-z}$ has no primitives over the annulus A={$z \in \mathbb{C}| 0< |z|<1 $}
So what I did is
Let $\gamma$ be a $C^1$ closed path from $[0,1]$ in $ \mathbb{C}$ such that
$\gamma (t) = \rho e^{2i\pi t} \forall t \in [0,1], \rho<1$

$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz= \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z^2-z}dz= \int_{\gamma} \frac{-1}{z}dz + \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z-1}  dz = -2i \pi + \int_{0}^{1}  \frac{1}{z
-1} dz $
And I don’t know how to progress further.
Plugging in $\gamma$ doesn’t seem to work and I can not use Cauchy formula since the annulus is not convex.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\int_{\gamma} \frac  1{z-1}dz=0$. It is because the integrand is analytic in $\{|z|<1\}$.

Comment: How can I show that the integrand is analytic ? Just started on complex analysis. Does this work : 
 $ \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z-1} dz = -log(1-z) +C $if $|z|<1 $?

Comment: $f/g$ is analytic if $f$ and $g$ are analytic and $g(z) \neq 0$. You should avoid using logarithms  in the complex plane until you are familiar with all the complications.

Comment: Could you give more details on why this integral goes to 0. I think I get why but we only saw Cauchy’s Theorem on open and convex parts of $\mathbb{C}$. So I cannot use it here since the annulus is open (intersection of two open disks) but not convex because of $z=0$

Comment: The fact that this integral equals $0$ is not related to the annulus at all. I am applying Cauchy's Theorem to the open unit disk which is convex.  @ValentinDesfrançois